How to route the root of a FastAPI application to separate files without "Prefix and path cannot be both empty" error?
I have tried numerous combinations to avoid getting a FastAPIError: Prefix and path cannot be both empty (path operation: root) error when trying to route my website to a separate .py file to separate the app a little. It also does not like having a Prefix of '' or '/'.
My goal is to get app.include_router(website.router) to route to website.py like it does for all the other routes.
The below works fine but I'd like to comment out the following lines in main.py:
@app.get('', include_in_schema=False)
@app.get("/")
async def root(request: Request, id: str = ""):
    response = templates.TemplateResponse(
        request=request, name="index.html", context={"id": id}
    )
    return response  

Then uncomment the website import from routers as well as app.include_router(website.router).
main.py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends, Form
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, RedirectResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

from asgi_csrf import asgi_csrf

from routers import, signup, users# ,website # <- uncomment this

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

app = FastAPI(
    root_path="/dev"
)

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

# move/comment the below into website.py
@app.get('', include_in_schema=False)
@app.get("/")
async def root(request: Request, id: str = ""):
    response = templates.TemplateResponse(
        request=request, name="index.html", context={"id": id}
    )
    return response  
# move/comment the above into website.py

# app.include_router(website.router) <- uncomment this
app.include_router(signup.router, prefix="/signup")
app.include_router(users.router, prefix="/users")

website.py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
import uuid

from typing import Annotated
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request, Cookie, Header, Depends, Form
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

from pydantic import BaseModel

router = APIRouter()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@router.get('', include_in_schema=False)
@router.get("/")
async def root(request: Request, id: str = ""):
    response = templates.TemplateResponse(
        request=request, name="index.html", context={"id": id}
    )
    return response  


Please remember that the order in which endpoints (and/or mounted apps) are defined matters. Please have a look at this answer and this answer for more details.

I don't understand what you mean. I want to migrate the currently working app.get to work as app.include_router(website.router).  When testing I comment out the app.get, uncomment the website import and the app.include_router(website.router).  I don't understand the relevance of the links which are mounting static on root.

@JohnnyJohnBoy As long as you register the route on just / (and not on both '' and /), it should work fine according to my tests.

FFS, I didn't try this assuming it would be the same for the root and it's not.  This works! Thank you.  Do you want to put it as an answer and I'll mark it correct so it might help someone else?
